# how to scrapy handle dns lookup failed

Tags: python, dns, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am looking to handle a DNS error when scraping domains Scrapy.

**Here's the error that I am seeing:**

```
ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://domain.com>: DNS lookup failed: address 'domain.com' not found [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

How could I be notified when I get an error like this, so that I can handle it myself without Scrapy just throwing an error and moving on.

Comment: you can use try catch method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `errback` along with callback:

```
Request(url, callback=your_callback, errback=your_errorback)
```

and `errback`:

```
def your_errorback(self, response):
    //your logic will be here
```

Answer (score 0):

please check value of
**allowed_domains** = ['abc.xyz.domain_name']
**start_urls** = ['http://abc.xyz.domain_name//']
may be in correct.