# Adding scrapy middleware from current script

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have setup my scrapy crawler in a single python script:

```
import sys
import csv
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    test = scrapy.Field()


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = [
        "blah.com",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        blahblah = MyItem()
        # Some Code
        yield blahblah


class crawler:
    def start(self):
        process = CrawlerProcess({
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
            'FEED_URI': 'Output.csv'
        })
        process.crawl(Spider)
        process.start()

app = crawler()
app.start()
```

and this is working perfectly.
Now how to add a scrapy middleware such as
`process_spider_exception(response, exception, spider)`
in this script and use it by adding that to `CrawlerProcess` settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem using twisted `errback` that can be used behind of it's `callback` and handle the error if `callback` throws an `exception`.

Relevant [question]: [how to scrapy handle dns lookup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840049/how-to-scrapy-handle-dns-lookup-failed)